# T-SQL - Select conditions Attributes in Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have problems how to search with multiple conditions.

Example: you want to buy shoes with attributes "Color Red" and "Size 10".

In my result, I don't know how to remove a shoes that have only the right color or size (I mean: I want to select only shoes have all attributes).

```
Declare @Tbl_Atributes Table
                       (
                            [NameAttribute] nvarchar(250),
                            [ValueAttribute] nvarchar(250)
                       )

Declare @Tbl_Product Table
                     (
                        [Code] int,
                        [Name] nvarchar(250),
                        [NameAttribute] nvarchar(250),
                        [ValueAttribute] nvarchar(250)
                     )

Insert Into @Tbl_Atributes 
values ('Color', 'Red'), ('Size', '10')

Insert Into @Tbl_Product ([Code], [Name], [NameAttribute], [ValueAttribute])
values ('1', 'Nike', 'Color', 'Red'),
       ('1', 'Nike', 'Color', 'Blue'),
       ('1', 'Nike', 'Size', '10'),
       ('2', 'Adidas', 'Size', '10')
```

I want to get products have all `NameAttribute` in `@Tbl_Atributes`.

My first attempt:

```
select tp.*
from @Tbl_Product tp
inner join @Tbl_Atributes as ta on tp.NameAttribute = ta.NameAttribute
                                and tp.ValueAttribute = ta.ValueAttribute
```

I meet the problem: product Adidas have 1 attribute Name: 'Size', and it's still in the result. (We need 2 attribute Name: Size and Color, only Nike have all)

Please, help me resolve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EXISTS:

```
select distinct [Code], [Name] from Tbl_Product t
where
  exists (
    select 1 from Tbl_Product 
    where [Code] = t.[Code] and [NameAttribute] = 'Color' and [ValueAttribute] = 'Red'
  )
  and 
  exists (
    select 1 from Tbl_Product 
    where [Code] = t.[Code] and [NameAttribute] = 'Size' and [ValueAttribute] = '10'
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd293566c482d59f0a0674bc8a68af2e)
**Edit**:
To get the products that have all the attributes from `Tbl_Atributes`:

```
select distinct [Code], [Name] from Tbl_Product t
where
(select count(distinct [NameAttribute]) from Tbl_Product where [Code] = t.[Code]) =
(select count(distinct [NameAttribute]) from Tbl_Atributes)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e05cd23a36c070a280a057ea8cb6a0f7)
**Edit2**:
For better performance use a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select count(distinct [NameAttribute]) total from Tbl_Atributes
)
select [Code], [Name] from Tbl_Product t
group by [Code], [Name]
having count(distinct [NameAttribute]) = (select total from cte)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a771426a392433f034a17926b92d279e)
You can replace `count(distinct [NameAttribute])` with `count(*)` if there is no case of duplicate attribute for a product.

Comment: oh, Thank you @forpas, but, I don't know exactly [NameAttribute] and [ValueAttribute] like your demo.
I've just give some example attribute in Tbl_Attribute,  and I want get product have all AttributeName in  Tbl_Attribute. (you see: only Nike )

Comment: @CristenRafalko I do not understand your question. [NameAttribute] and [ValueAttribute] are the columns in your table `Tbl_Product`.

Comment: yeah, your solution resolve case, but I want to ask how about perfomance, when I run you code, and we have 100.000 products.

Comment: If you change "Insert Into @Tbl_Atributes values ('Color', 'Red'), ('Size', '11')", result comes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found solution like that;

```
Declare @Tbl_Atributes Table(
[NameAttribute] nvarchar(250)
,[ValueAttribute] nvarchar(250))

Declare @Tbl_Product Table(
    [Code] int,
    [Name] nvarchar(250),
    [NameAttribute] nvarchar(250)
    ,[ValueAttribute] nvarchar(250))

Insert Into @Tbl_Atributes values ('Color', 'Red'), ('Size', '10')

Insert Into @Tbl_Product  ([Code],[Name], [NameAttribute], [ValueAttribute])
values ('1','Nike','Color','Red'),('1','Nike','Color','Blue'),('1','Nike','Size','10')
        ,('2','Addidas','Size','10')


select tmp.* 
from (select tp1.Code, tp1.Name
        from @Tbl_Product tp1 
        group by tp1.Code,tp1.Name) as tmp    
where (select COUNT(1) from @Tbl_Atributes)=
        (select count(1) 
        from @Tbl_Product tp
        join @Tbl_Atributes ta on tp.NameAttribute=ta.NameAttribute and tp.ValueAttribute=ta.ValueAttribute
        where tp.Code=tmp.Code)
```

Comment: Hi Murat,  your solution was the first my solution. but, It's not resolve, because, the result will have product Adidas, It's have 1 Attribute Name:  Size.

Comment: oh, I don't have product code in table attribute because It's table Condition for Searching in Table Product.
Inner join & join can't not pass all condition, it's only pass Exists condition in Table_Attribute.

Comment: @CristenRafalko If you change Size 10 to 11 or any other ValueAttributes in Tbl_Atributes, you will get still same result, but i wrote new answer that also provides ValueAttribute.

Comment: oh, the result is correct. but, you think it's will good performance when products are 100.000 rows?

Comment: Sorry I just found this. I don’t know this code performance on high data. You could try.

Comment: @CristenRafalko I wrote write answer but you didn't mention this as right answer:)